# Why does Excel VBA calling an add-in function crash Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-addins, xll

I am running 32-bit Excel 2010 (Windows 10.1) with an add-in loaded (which I developed). I need to call one of the add-in functions (I will call it `changeText`) from VBA.

I've written the following VBA code behind one of the worksheets:

```
Sub MakeChange()

    Dim result As String

    result = Application.Run("changeText", "teststring")

    Debug.Print result
    Debug.Print "Complete"

End Sub
```

and assigned this Sub to a button on that worksheet.

If I run this function directly from within the VBA editor it works fine every time and returns the correct result to the Debug window.

If I call the function from within Excel by pressing the button, I get a Type Mismatch error (via a message box) the first time. If I then press the button again, everything hangs and the only way out is to kill the process.

If I move the function to a workbook-level module, more or less the same thing happens - I get a Type Mismatch error on the `Application.Run` line to which I click 'End', then the same again on the second click but this time the application hangs after pressing 'End'.

The add-in is mature and the function being called works perfectly when called directly from within Excel or otherwise invoked by the add-in. The XLL function being called takes a string and returns a string.

Does anyone have any idea what could be happening here, and in particular why the application is crashing?

Comment: try Dim Result as Variant and inspect what Result actually contains ...

Comment: Thanks @charleswilliams, good idea. It contains Error 2000 (i.e. #NULL!). This is baffling (to me, at least). The function is being called identically as far as I can see (but clearly it must not be). Why does it make a difference whether I invoke the macro via a button or directly in the VBA editor? The inputs to Application.Run are identical in each case. (And when declared as a variant, a second invocation still fatally hangs Excel.)

Comment: @Neil, you can't assign a `Null` result to a `String`

Comment: It's very hard to tell what is causing the function to crash without seeing the code of the `changeText` function.  You say the function takes a string and returns a string, but what other resources does it use while getting from input to output?

Comment: So run the XLL function in debug mode and step through to find out whats happening

Comment: I will do as @CharlesWilliams suggests and hopefully this will shed some light, but what I continue not to understand is how this result can be any different in the two cases. I'm executing exactly the same code, except that in one case I'm pressing 'Run' in the VBA editor and in the other I'm pressing a worksheet button to run it. As far as the XLL is concerned, what's the difference? Anyway, thanks for suggestions - I will try to debug the XLL and report back...

Comment: @Neil - the context is different, the focus is probably different, methods like Application.Caller are different etc. I could wildly speculate but it would be better to pinpoint the problem.